# Mapbox Expression to check property of MGLStyleLayer and compare with string

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-ios

In the `mapView:didFinishLoadingStyle:` method, I would like to be able to check to see if a `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` uses a specific `class`, similar to how we can use `filter` in a JSON style file to apply a style to only a certain class:

[image]

However, in my case, I want to check and see if a class exists on the map, and then hide it if it is part of an array of strings:

```
NSArray *poiTypesExcluded = @[@"airport"];
for (NSString *poiType in poiTypesExcluded) {
        
    layer.visible = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"class != %@", poiType];
        
}
```

This is giving me the error:

`Unable to parse the format string "class != %@ == 1"`.

**Any help on how to write the `NSExpression` to be able to compare a `class` property to another string?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasted a lot of time on this, and in the end it was easier than I thought:

```
NSArray *poiTypesExcluded = @[@"airport", @"grocery", @"bank"];
NSMutableArray *predicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *poiType in poiTypesExcluded) {
    
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class != %@", poiType]];
    
}

symbolLayer.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```